How Can a Gas Cooktop with a Smaller cut-out be Installed into a Larger cut-out?
I rent a lovely apartment whose kitchen was recently remodeled to include Ceasarstone counters. Is it possible to somehow, reduce the counter cut-out in the Ceasarstone if the gas cooktop with which I might replace the current gas cooktop (which required a larger cut-out)? I certainly don't want to damage my landlord's counters and, of course, want to be sure the smaller gas cooktop would be properly supported and ventilated underneath should this change take place. Thanks for any worthy information you can provide!

I would have thought that the landlord would be responsible for selecting and installing a gas cooktop. What country is this? But if he is letting the tennant install what they want, it ought to be straightforward to construct a cradle that would allow installation of a smaller cooktop than the opening. What is the size of the opening and what are the reqirements of the cooktop you want to install? Edit your question and put all this into the question. Adding a picture would also help.

As a renter you do not have the right on your own to replace an already installed gas cooktop. There are serious liability considerations.

Get a sheet of stainless steel cut (or fabricated) that matches the outline of the old cooktop  and has a hole the size the new cooktop needs.
have the edges of the hole rolled over where they are unsupported improve rigidity.

stainless steel welding is hard and (and consquentially) expensive.   cutting a hole is probably going to be the best price. note that some of the hole material is being used to stiffen the edges of the sheet.

Really no,  you make a drawing and take it to the sheet metal shop,  they tell you a price and when it will be ready.  if they can do it cheaper by welding they will tell you.  OP is living in rented accomodation - they probably don't have a bending brake or a TIG welder.
